# Find offset between system-time and Internet time using Python

Tags: python, systemtime

How would you find the time offset between the local OS system-time and Internet time from various Internet time sources using Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ntplib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ntplib/). Right from the manual:

```
>>> import ntplib
>>> c = ntplib.NTPClient()
>>> response = c.request('europe.pool.ntp.org', version=3)
>>> response.offset
-0.143156766891
```

Comment: This is an old question but what does the negative or positive offset mean? I am not sure which one is ahead, the PC time or time server time?

Comment: @wondim positive = remote NTP server is ahead. In the example in the answer itself, my local clock was slightly too fast.

Comment: Thank you! Mine was -4 so it is strange how it goes that ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Just to save you some time. Here's the code I ended up with using phihag's answer. It prints the drift every `interval_sec` to screen and to a log file.
You'll need to `easy_install ntplib` for it to work.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='time_shift.txt',level=logging.DEBUG)

import ntplib
import time
import datetime
c = ntplib.NTPClient()

interval_sec = 60
while True:
    try:
        response = c.request('europe.pool.ntp.org', version=3)
        txt = '%s     %.3f' % (datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(), response.offset)
        print txt
        logging.info(txt)
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(interval_sec)
```